# Pandas how to index a a list from JSON and put it into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, sentiment-analysis

How can I index a list inside a dataframe?

I have this code here that will get data from JSON and insert it into a dataframe

Here's what the JSON looks like

```
{"text_sentiment": "positive", "text_probability": [0.33917574607174916, 0.26495590980799744, 0.3958683441202534]}
```

Here's my code.

```
input_c = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Comments','Result'])
for i in range(input_df.shape[0]):
    url = 'http://classify/?text='+str(input_df.iloc[i])
    r = requests.get(url)
    result = r.json()["text_sentiment"]
    proba = r.json()["text_probability"]
    input_c = input_c.append({'Comments': input_df.loc[i].to_string(index=False),'Result': result, 'Probability': proba}, ignore_index = True)
st.write(input_c)
```

Here's what the results look like
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbBym.png)

```
                                     Comments      Result                              Probability
0                This movie is good in my eyes.   neutral    [0.26361889609129974, 0.4879752378104797, 0.2484058660982205]
1            This is a bad movie it's not good.  negative   [0.5210904912792065, 0.22073131008688818, 0.25817819863390534]
2     One of the best performance in this year.  positive   [0.14644707145500369, 0.3581522311734714, 0.49540069737152503]
3                The best movie i've ever seen.  positive   [0.1772046003747405, 0.026468108571479156, 0.7963272910537804]
4                             The movie is meh.   neutral   [0.24349393167653663, 0.6820982528652574, 0.07440781545820596]
5  One of the best selling artist in the world.  positive    [0.07738688706903311, 0.3329095061233371, 0.5897036068076298]
```

The data in the Probability column is the one I want to index.

For example: If the value in Result is "positive" then I want the proba to index to 2,and If the result is "neutral" index to 1

Like this

```
                                      Comments     Result        Probability
0                This movie is good in my eyes.   neutral    [0.4879752378104797]
1            This is a bad movie it's not good.  negative    [0.5210904912792065]
2     One of the best performance in this year.  positive   [0.49540069737152503]
3                The best movie i've ever seen.  positive    [0.7963272910537804]
4                             The movie is meh.   neutral    [0.6820982528652574]
5  One of the best selling artist in the world.  positive    [0.5897036068076298]
```

Are there any ways on how to do it?

Comment: Any chance you can post the dataframe as code/csv instead of image? Thanks.

Comment: @Ankur added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you already decided the `Result` content, whether it's negative, neutral, or positive, so you need only to store the maximum value of the probability list in the data frame `input_c`.

This means, change `'Probability': proba` to `'Probability': max(proba)`, so modify:

```
 input_c = input_c.append({'Comments': input_df.loc[i].to_string(index=False),'Result': result, 'Probability': proba}, ignore_index = True)
```

to

```
 input_c = input_c.append({'Comments': input_df.loc[i].to_string(index=False),'Result': result, 'Probability': max(proba}, ignore_index = True)
```

then to set the index in `input_c`  to `Probability` column, use

```
input_c.set_index('Probability')
```